# Android-how to change color on button and change visibility on layout, from other class?

Tags: java, android, button

when i click on a button:

1: It should change button color to red, and other buttons to white.

2: Make a layout visible and other layout invisible.

My code looks like this:

---

### SimpleActivity

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  protected Button arealBtn;
  protected LinearLayout arealLayout;
  private SimpleBtnClk simpleBtnClk;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

    simpleBtnClk = new SimpleBtnClk();

    arealBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arealbtn);

     arealLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.arealLayout);


    arealBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            simpleBtnClk.ArealBtn(); 

            //arealLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //arealBtn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //lengthLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //lengthBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    });
}

}
```

---

### SimpleBtnClk class:

```
package simpleapps.com.converterv1;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class SimpleBtnClk extends SimpleActivity{


public void ArealBtn(){
    arealLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    arealBtn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    lengthLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lengthBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

---

Now if i remove

> simpleBtnClk.ArealBtn();

and remove comment marks on

> arealLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     arealBtn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
>     lengthLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>     lengthBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

then it works fine, but when i try to use the code  *simpleBtnClk.ArealBtn();* the app stops working.

I cant see the problem, been starring at it for 4 days and i am just cant see it.

-edit:

1 maybe i should have stated that i am new to java, android and programming.

Comment: How you able to access simpleBtnClk.ArealBtn(); as its not static???

Comment: You can use the shared preferences for that. Save the variables to it from your second activity and when you come back to the first activity use the shared preference to load the values to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass reference on your activity in your second class, so you can add it to parameter or pass it to class constructor, and then via reference you can change your button.

For example with parameter it would look like:

```
public void ArealBtn(SimpleAcvitvity activity){
    activity.arealLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activity.arealBtn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    activity.lengthLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    activity.lengthBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

And in your first activity change field from protected to public;

From this:

```
  protected Button arealBtn;
  protected LinearLayout arealLayout;
```

To this:

```
  public Button arealBtn;
  public LinearLayout arealLayout;
```

And also your forgot to create reference to lengthLayout and lengthBtn.

Hope it would help.

Comment: i did what Intsab Haider said in the comment,  static Button arealBtn; and now it works, how ever i need to read up on this and the solution you gave me.

Comment: Create a static fields is bad approach... It can cause leaks in memory